# Tomcat upgrade replacing ROOT.war

Tags: linux, redhat, tomcat

When upgrading tomcat by running:

```
yum update
```

on Amazon Linux the ROOT.war file is replaced by the default ROOT.war from the tomcat distribution.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with yum but you probably installed a package for Tomcat Sample web app or something like that - that's how it is with apt on debian based distro like Ubuntu. Just don't install it, then your update won't update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was:

```
yum remove tomcat7-webapps
```

You then need to reinstall your ROOT.war.
The remove the ROOT folder

Restart tomcat